# Web form filling automation using selenium for drop downs dates

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, automation

I am looking for a solution using which I can fill the dropdown date in a website using my excel data.

I am currently using selenium library in Excel VBA for webform fill automation but stuck at this task.

I Will be really grateful if anybody can help. Please let me know if any other information is required on this, will share the info actively.

I have used

```
obj.Findelementbyxpath("someXpath").click
obj.Findelementbyxpath("someXpath").sendkeys(reference to this workbook)
```

but no date got selected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You literally gave no information at all. *All* the relevant information is missing. Furthermore you didn't show what you have done/tried yet. You might benefit from reading [ask] and 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613) • Note that SO is not a free code writing service. So we can only help you if you have a specific issue with your code and ask a precise question to that issue.

Comment: Please check out what a [mcve] is and how to provide one. We need the relevant VBA code and the relevant HTML code including a concrete description of what went wrong. 2 lines of code is not enough information.